# Getting total sales data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables

```
bills
billId | bar     | drinker  | date     | time
0001   | SomeBar |  Jon Doe | 11-13-18 | 08:10
0002   | SomeBar |  Jane Doe| 11-10-18 | 10:10
0003   | twoBar  |  Mike Doe| 11-11-18 | 12:12

transactions
billID | item | quantity
0001   | bud  | 3
0002   | bud  | 3
0003   | coors| 1
```

How add up the total number of a beers that one bar sells? I understand that I can use inner join because they both share a billId, and I understand this query to count the total of a single table would be something like this.

```
SELECT item, SUM(quantity) AS TotalQuantity
FROM transactions
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC; 

Select * FROM bills inner JOIN transactions ON bills.billId = transactions.billID AND bar = SOMEBAR;
```

Comment: thank you for including text with showing table structure and sample data instead of screenshots!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you should use the `GROUP BY` statement to, well, group by the variable you want grouped:

```
SELECT b.bar, sum(t.quantity) as total
FROM bills b INNER JOIN transactions t ON b.billId = t.billId
GROUP BY b.bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the `bills` table and group by `bar` like this:

```
SELECT bar, SUM(quantity)
FROM transactions t
    JOIN bills b USING (billID)
GROUP BY b.bar;
```